# boto3 pkg error

Tags: software-installation

I am using aws cloud service using boto3 package thro python programs.
I reinstalled python3 in vmware sbox[ubuntu] and downloaded boto3 using pip.
now iam getting run time errors.
boto3 is incompatible with python3.6?
if so do I uninstall python3 and use default python?
appreciate suggestions

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the actual errors you are getting. We can't really help without knowing what the issue is. No, you shouldn't remove python3. In fact, python2 will be end of life in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Remove boto3 installed by pip:

```
sudo pip uninstall boto3
sudo pip3 uninstall boto3
```

Install boto3 from repository

```
sudo apt-get install python-boto3
sudo apt-get install python3-boto3
```

Comment: Whilst this is a suggestion and may help, there's no reason that boto3 should cause python to fail when run from pip. "Use the OS packages," is not always the answer.

Comment: You can add your own answer. And then we compare the votes count.

Comment: "Use the OS packages" is legitimate advice because some of the packages that are listed in PyPI are not maintained as well as their counterpart packages in the default Ubuntu repositories.