# Is there a safe way to upgrade boto3 system wide?

Tags: python

(I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

I make daily use of `awscli`, which I installed with apt and it works just fine.  However the version of `boto3` that came with it is very old (1.9.253) by comparison to the most recent version (1.20.3).  Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, but there appears to be a bug in this version of boto3 that prevents me from writing any scripts that need to use AWS's SSO interface:

```
import boto3                                                                                      
boto3.setup_default_session()                                                                     
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')                                                           
client.list_secrets()  # NoCredentialsError
```

Running the same code in a virtualenv running a modern version of boto3 renders the expected output, so I figure it's the wide version gap that's at fault here.

I know that I *could* just run `pip install --upgrade boto3` as root, but that'd likely cause all manner of stuff breaking, so I'm looking for a cleaner/safer alternative.  Does one exist?  At the moment I'm looking at starting little virtualenvs everywhere and writing wrapper aliases to use that python instance to run my scripts but that feels nasty too.

Comment: You mentioned that the most recent version of boto3 works in a virtual environment but not on your physical machine.  What type of virtual environment are you running boto3 on?  Is it possible for you to determine what may be different in the virtual environment from your physical machine?

Comment: It's a standard virtualenv created with `python3 -m venv my_virtualenv`.  The only thing *different* is the boto3 version that gets installed into it when I run `pip install boto3`.

Comment: According to this documentation, it states that you need to install python 3.6 or later.  this is the source https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html   Is it possible to do this on your machine?

Comment: I'm already running Python 3.8.10 as that's what comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: According to the same source there's a command `# Install Boto3 version 1.0 specifically`
`pip install boto3==1.0.0`  Did you try changing that to `pip install boto3==1.20.3`  It may override the install version.

Comment: It's generally a Bad Idea to run `pip` against the system-installed Python.  I can obviously upgrade boto3 in a virtualenv, but I don't want to change the version of the system-installed boto3 directly like that as it would likely have unintented (and hard to fix) repercussions.

Comment: found this in the forum:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024932/boto3-pkg-error/1024940#1024940  This is definitely the best I can do.  Otherwise you can try official boto3 sites and see what you can do there, you can search more in this forum or try some other official ubuntu sites.

Comment: Bug reports may help but I'm not certain about that.